# Select Statement In SQL Update using 3 different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 different tables that i need to use in this update statement. My question is how do i get the third table involved in the statement? I know that join works. I need to use the joined table's ID to get the name of the primary divsion in the third table.

Here is what i have:

```
UPDATE EmployeeMaster
SET PrimaryDivision = (SELECT DivisionName WHERE ID = d.PrimaryDivision FROM DivisionTable)
FROM EmployeeMaster e
JOIN EmployeeDivisions d ON e.UserName = d.UserName
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be what you want:

```
UPDATE e
SET e.PrimaryDivision = dt.DivisionName 
FROM EmployeeMaster e
INNER JOIN EmployeeDivisions d 
    ON e.UserName = d.UserName
INNER JOIN DivisionTable dt
    ON d.PrimaryDivision = dt.ID
```